# endif; resulting in 'Parse error'

Tags: php

```
<?php

if(!empty($_POST['email'] && !empty($_POST['password']));

endif;

?>
```

This is the only PHP I have in the file and i get this error message when I try to execute. It was working before any PHP was added. Newbie to PHP please be nice.

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';' in E:\Kasim\Gemcode\PHP\auth\login.php on line 3

When I take out the ';' it brings this up:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'endif' (T_ENDIF) in E:\Kasim\Gemcode\PHP\auth\login.php o

Comment: one `)` missed :- `if(!empty($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['password']));`

Comment: you're not using `if: endif` correctly. please check http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php
also, your if doesn't really stand for much... it doesn't do anything.

Comment: The first `;` ends your `if`

Comment: @hummingBird gave the answer. Period. And close all parentheses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one `)` missed :-

So it should be:-

```
if(!empty($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['password']));
```

Also your code seems in-correct based on manual example:-  http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php

```
<?php
if ($a == 5): // check here
    echo "a equals 5";
    echo "...";
elseif ($a == 6):
    echo "a equals 6";
    echo "!!!";
else:
    echo "a is neither 5 nor 6";
endif;
?>
```

Note:- Based on this example you need to correct your code.